# SilverStripe Subsite module delete all related data on subsite deletion

Tags: silverstripe

I m using `Silverstripe subsite module`. When `Subsite` is deleted I want to delete all other information related to Subsite as well, like, `Domains, Settings` etc. I have created an `extension` that'll extend `Subsite` model.

```
<?php

class SubsiteExtension extends DataExtension {

        public function onAfterWrite(){
             parent::onAfterWrite();
             //Some codes here
        }

        public function onBeforeDelete(){
            //Check if member exist for Subsite, if so show warning.
        }

        public function onAfterDelete(){
            $id = $this->owner->ID;

            //DELETE ALL SUBDOMAINS RELATED TO DELETED SUBSITE
            DB::query("DELETE FROM SubsiteDomain WHERE SubsiteID='".$id."'");

            //DELETE SITE CONFIG 
            DB::query("DELETE FROM SiteConfig WHERE SubsiteID='".$id."'");

        }


}
```

**Problem**

1. The code works flawlessly. Just wondering is there any other better way of deleting related records from other tables??
2. On method `onBeforeDelete` , how to show custom message saying "You can't delete this subsite unless you delete all the members" ?

Comment: I wouldn't delete things in this way incase it is an accident or that you require the data later (e.g. for reporting) so I'd suggest this kind of approach... https://github.com/lekoala/silverstripe-softdelete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `onAfterDelete` to delete related records is perfectly fine, although it really sounds a lot like you're doing unnecessary work here. Who's going to be bothered by some stray DB entries?

Regarding your `onBeforeDelete` approach: I would solve it otherwise. Override `canDelete` in your extension instead, something like this:

```
public function canDelete($member)
{
    if( /* check if member exist for Subsite */ ){
        return false;
    }
    // returning null here means that this extension doesn't influence 
    // the delete permission at this point
    return null;
}
```

This will prevent deleting of the record in the CMS. Additionally, you could use `updateCMSFields` to display a notice to the user why he can't delete the record.

```
public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields) 
{
    if (!$this->owner->canDelete()) {
        $fields->addFieldToTab(
            'Root.Main', 
            LiteralField::create('_deleteInfo', 'Your info text')
        );
    }
}
```